# Naval Engagements in the Warp

Tags: warhammer-40k, space-combat

Is it possible for vessels to engage in combat while within the Warp?

I can find many bits of information relating to the fighting of daemonic incursions while in the Warp, so presumably weapons must work. But I can't find any example of ships firing on each other, can anyone shed the Emperors light on this topic?

Comment: The problem is more finding one another inside the warp. It is a different dimension with different angles, time, .... its pure chaos. The demons find oyu anyway as to them you are like s stone thron into a lake...an anomaly and they are almost everywhere in the warp. So even if the weapons work I guess the chances are that the ships won't be able to find each other. additionally....it is questionable if the weapons have any effect outside their respective geller field.

Comment: Would this also hinder pursuit of a fleeing ship through the Warp as well?

Comment: @CyanAngel with a talented [Navigator](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Navigator), you could chase a ship through the warp. One Navigator can sense another and distinguish between several in the warp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes with a but...

I can't specifically recall any ships ever actually engaging in a ship-to-ship battle in the [immaterium](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Immaterium). Possibly the [Eisenstein](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/The_Flight_of_the_Eisenstein_(Novel))?

But even if two enemy Imperium ships met in the warp, there would very likely no combat at all, the risk is just too high.

Imperium ships are protected from the inhabitants of the warp by a [Gellar Field](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Gellar_Field), which encompasses their ships in a bubble of real space, shielding them from the warp. If a ship was to engage in a battle, powering weapons batteries, shields and tactical maneuvers would all divert power from the Gellar Field, risking it's failure. In fact a ship which could power all four simultaneously would have to be monstrous in size.

Plus there is the obvious risk of the field being knocked out by enemy fire.

Theoretically however, Orks could blow chunks out of each others ships and still be protected from the creatures of the warp. It's their innate collective psychic power that repels any demonic incursion, not any technological field or barrier.

Eldar, Necron and Tyranid ships don't travel in the warp at all.

Thanks to [CyanAngel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/25029/cyanangel) for the comment:

> Tau use Warp skimming, similar to pre Age of Strife Mankind, alot slower then travelling through the Warp, but removes the need for a Gellar field.

Comment: If I can dig up an example of some ships firing on each other, I'll update this answer. I half remember a battle in the warp but it could have been a ship defending itself against some creature of the immaterium, just can't be positive.

Comment: Tau use Warp skimming, similar to pre Age of Strife Mankind, alot slower then travelling through the Warp, but removes the need for a Gellar field.

Great answer, I had thought about the risks, but with two major enemies of man not needing to worry about exposure during travel in the Warp, I presumed that combat must be nearly inevitable.

Comment: @CyanAngel probably the only real risk of a battle taking place is if someone is unlucky enough to meet an Ork ship in the warp. I'm going to search for an instance of that or something similar, I actually really want to know now...

Comment: I would imagine The Chaos forces don't have to concern themselves with the dangers of fighting during Warp travel either. I was hoping the fiction behind the Gothic War would cover this topic, but no luck.

Comment: @CyanAngel Well I think it depends on who they are. If they have a soul, be they a chaos cultist or imperial guard, they would be fair game for creatures in the warp. Creatures in the warp function on pure instinct and so probably don't differentiate between Chaos and Imperium ships / crews. The likes of [Abaddon](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Ezekyle_Abaddon) might be protected by a higher power as they've done so much for Chaos.

Comment: @daft I think there was a mention in one of the blood raven books (an eldar ship who was half in warp and got quite destroyed OR a thunderhawk that went through the warp) but not 100% if there was a battle there unfolding in warp

Comment: In recent years Tau learned how to get into the warp... but they haven't learned about the Gellar field. Fortunately for them, they are almost invisible to the demons, but you couldn't say the same for their allies. http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Fourth_Sphere_of_Expansion